# Evaluate a limit involving the inverse of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, inverse-function

Let $f : [1, \infty) \to [1, \infty)$ be a function such that $f(x) = x(1 + \ln x)$. Prove that $f$ is bijective and then calculate:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(x) \ln x}{x}$$

I have no difficulties in proving that $f$ is bijective, but I can't calculate the limit. I've tried using l'Hospital's rule but got nothing meaningful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd like to know this too, I'm not sure, but maybe rewrite your limit in the inverse form, and then solve for $y \to \infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is bijective then there exists a unique $b$ such that $x=f(b)$ and if $x\to\infty$ then so does $b\to\infty$ and using that $f^{-1}(f(b))=b$ you're looking at
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{b\ln f(b)}{f(b)}=\frac{b(\ln(b(1+\ln b)))}{b(1+\ln b)}=\frac{\ln(b)+\ln(1+\ln b)}{1+\ln b}{=^{L'h}}\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b(1+\ln b)}}{\frac{1}{b}}=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{1+\ln b}}{1}=1$$